# How do I install shogun's python interface?

Tags: python, shogun

I'm on a Mac. Step 1:

`sudo conda install -c conda-forge shogun`

Step 2:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import shogun
>>> from shogun import RealFeatures, PolyKernel, CSVFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name RealFeatures
```

I also tried on Fedora using the RPMs. After verifying that the C++ interface works (`gcc shogun.cpp -I/usr/include/shogun/base -lshogun -L/usr/lib64/libshogun.*`) I followed the instructions [here](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/examples/latest/quickstart/interfaces.html) and set `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/modshogun.py`

And then:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, May 10 2017, 20:04:36)
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shogun
>>> from shogun import RealFeatures, PolyKernel, CSVFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name RealFeatures
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably that shogun's docs are currently for the in-development version 6.1, but the conda package is for the latest actual release 6.0. In 6.0, you need to do `from modshogun import RealFeatures`; the `shogun` package is the old interface, and the modern "modular" one is `modshogun`. This will be renamed to just `shogun` in the upcoming 6.1 release.